# Flexbox how to have div take up height of rest of page

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I'm using flexbox and am my page is set up the following way:

```
Parent (flex-direction: row)

   -Child 1: (flex-direction: column)

   -Child 2: (flex-direction: column)
```

Child 2 contains a div for which I want to take up the full height of the rest of the page and be responsive.  My question is:  how do I accomplish this?

https://plnkr.co/edit/9Awc5IOp9jYUTRBhUj9L

Thats a pretty close representation of the model I am working with.

Screen cap (I need yellow to go to bottom of page)
https://gyazo.com/91ba070b8bd9b5396b892c967df33336

Parent isn't the parent of the page.  There are still 1-2 more levels above this parent for the root component.

Parent component less:

```
.container {

  .search-and-list {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;

      .search {
          width: 25%;
          padding: 10px 16px;
      }

      .list {
          flex: 1 1 auto;
          padding: 10px 20px 0 0;
      }
  }
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <header (toggleNewBucketWindow)="bucketChangeState($event)"></header>
  <div class="search-and-list">
    <search class="search"></search>
     <question-list class="list"></question-list>
   </div>
</div>
```

Child less:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;


  .label {
      color: #ccc;
      font-size: 12px;
  }

  .list {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-right: 16px;
      background: yellow;
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%;
  }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="label">{{title}}</p>
  <div class="list">

  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: The html and body tags already have a height set to 100% in my project.

EDIT2: Updated jsfiddle to plunker project

EDIT3: Added screen cap

EDIT4: Adding CSS/HTML

Comment: Since the `parent` is defined to have `flex: row`, the 2 of its children will be aligned on a single row. Then what do you mean by "take up the full height of the rest of the page" ?

Comment: I need the row to take up the full height of the rest of the page and height: 100% does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use VH parameter ([Viewport height](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/))

**EDIT: Removed the default page margin / padding to avoid the scrollbar.**

CodePen:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrBWXm

```
<style>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.parent{
display:flex;
height:100vh;
background-color:azure;
}

.child{
display:flex;
}

</style>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Example</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I do that, it extends beyond the bottom of the page and I get a scroll bar.  My coworker said he did height: calc(~"100vh - 133px"); which does work for me, but I find it kind of hacky.  I feel as if there's a more elegant solution.  Plus, that solution only works if the component is placed in the exact spot...

Comment: Edited my code to remove the default page padding / margin. This fixes it. Hope that's what you needed.